# sizeWithAttributes gets me a different CGSize width and height

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7

In iOS 7 `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated. The suggested  replacement method is `sizeWithAttributes:`
But when I change the method from `sizeWithFont:`  to `sizeWithAttributes:` 
I get different Values.

Here my Code:

```
CGSize temp = [opt.option sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[self randomFontSize]]];
NSLog(@"Old SizeWithFont value %f x %f",temp.height, temp.width);

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:[self randomFontSize]]};
temp = [opt.option sizeWithAttributes: attributes];
NSLog(@"New SizeWithAttribute has value %f x %f",temp.height, temp.width);
```

And the output is :

```
linespacing 16.33, fontsize 16.00
Old SizeWithFont value 18.000000 x 47.000000
New SizeWithAttribute has value 17.875000 x 46.250000
```

Do I'm doing something wrong ? I

Comment: This seems to be the expected behaviour according to the documentation. The functions differ in how they round the returned values.

Comment: Note that a clearer experiment would use literal constants for the font name, font size, string being measured, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributed text method description implies a behavior difference (boldface added by me)...

> This method returns **fractional sizes**; to use a returned size to size
>   views, you must raise its value to the nearest higher integer using
>   the ceil function.

It also states that integral sizes should be computed with `ceil()` (in other words round-up).  Doing so makes your experiment work as expected...

```
NSLog(@"New SizeWithAttribute has value %f x %f",ceil(temp.height), ceil(temp.width));
```

Comment: Thanks danh, I thing you surely meant I got to round NSLog(@"New SizeWithAttribute has value %f x %f",ceil(temp.height), ceil(temp.width));